# How to give write permission for a Junit test using gradle

Tags: java, linux, gradle, junit, build.gradle

I have a test suite that is configed in Java gradle. The Junit tests involves io file write/read
When I use window machine and `gradlew.bat test`, all tests pass.
However, if I try to run the same test suite in linux machine, all the test involves writing file io fails. 
I think the problem is that permission. Is there any way I can fix it?

How I created the file:

```
    File file = new File(String.format("./%s/e2eTest/Delete/Hello.txt", root));

    file.createNewFile();

    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
    writer.write("Test data\n");
    writer.close();
```

How I access the file:

```
Unirest.delete(String.format("http://localhost:%d/e2etest/delete/hello.txt",port)).asString().getStatus();
```

Server side:

```
File f = new File(root+request.getUri())
```

Comment: @janos the output is just junit assert mismatch due to a non-exist file (the file is created in the test setup)

Comment: Show the file creation and access please.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that you have write access, I suggest that you create files under the folder specified by the `java.io.tmpdir` system property.

A simple way to do this is in a junit test is by using the [TemporaryFolder](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule which will delete everything after the test has finished.

eg:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void myFileTest() throws IOException {
        File testFile = folder.newFile("myfile.txt");
        doStuff(testFile);
    }
}
```

See also [File.createTempFile(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))